# Calling MACRO DEFINED TABLE GoogleSQL (BigQuery)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I've a select function inside a macro which creates a table. This table has u_id, timestamp & type

I want to call this MACRO as another table so that I can join it to an existing query.

I keep running into issues in GoogleSQL, it's telling me '$' is illegal....

I'm not sure if I'm defining or calling the macro correctly.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Query is as follows;

```
SELECT a.*, k.timestamp FROM table1 as a
LEFT JOIN $macro1 as k 
ON a.u_id = k.u_id
 
--//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
--Define Table of Issues
--//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

DEFINE MACRO macro1 (

SELECT 
       main.u_id,
       main.timestamp,
       main.type  
       
       FROM table1 as main
       
       where main.type = 'ISSUE'

);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix, macro needs to be placed above SELECT statement